How do satellites authenticate command input?
Layman question here. Apparently we're still sending radio commands to Voyager 1, launched in 1977. How are these commands authenticated to make sure they come from NASA and not from someone else with a sufficiently powerful antenna? Surely whatever crypto they used in 1977 is now completely broken, and I imagine the Voyager's processor is not powerful enough to use modern signature systems. Is transmission based on "security by obscurity", so that the format of the commands is kept secret? Could in theory anyone with a transmitter "hack" Voyager?
And how do newer satellites solve the same problem?

I have read somewhere that for the Voyager probes, it's mostly "security by economics of building the huge antenna required to communicate with it"

New satellites have encrypted communication, both uplink and downlink (telemetry at least). The sophistication of the encryption correlates with the importance of the satellite ;-)

While DES, publicly recommended algorithm at the time, isn't secure today.  It was optimized for the computing power available at the time.  They knew the long lifetime of Voyager would require something more secure, and it would not have been difficult at all to extend it (e.g. Tripple DES) to something that would last well beyond Voyager's practical lifetime, at the expense of very slightly more computing power.
